# get custom fields from SharePoint list item

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Using the beta SharePoint REST API (using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/listitems_list)).
Would like to get all items for a list, including the content of custom fields.

When I use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}?expand=columns,items(expand=fields)` I see (in my case):

- `columns` containing 32 fields, including standard ones (e.g. `ID`,
  `Title`, `Status`) and the custom ones (e.g. `Next_action`)
- `fields` containing only the default (in my case 23) fields, including `id` [note it is lower case], `Title` and `Status` fields and -as expected- not the custom ones.

The [documentation shows an example of getting specific columns](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/listitems_list).
When I use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields(select=ID,Title,Status,Next_action)`

Then I get an array with all items, and per item the object `fields` that only contains the property `id`.

So: the other standard fields (`Title`, `Status`) and the custom field `Next_action` do not show up.

How do I get the values for a list of standard and custom fields?

---

**EDIT:** more details about the lists that I have:

A couple of the lists are default ones that have been customized (I believe Tasks, Issues, Risks), others are completely custom (Decisions, Changes). The Tasks lists has versioning.
Some observations:

- Decisions list has no missing fields (=no difference between `columns` and the actual `fields`)
- all of them have "missing": ID|Author|Editor|DocIcon|AppAuthor|AppEditor, and fields that are not in the Columns: id|AuthorLookupId|EditorLookupId; both can be explained I guess (note that ID in column and id in field)
- the missing fields are a variety of types: text (rich / plain, single / multi line), number, choice, etc.

Possibly related, when using Flow I create a trigger for "when an item is created or modified", I am then presented with only 2 lists (Changes and Decisions). Missing: Tasks, Risks, Issues.

**Tasks**

- fields (19): "Title|Predecessors|Priority|Status|PercentComplete|AssignedTo|Body|StartDate|Checkmark|ContentType|Modified|Created|_UIVersionString|Attachments|Edit|LinkTitleNoMenu|LinkTitle|ItemChildCount|FolderChildCount"
- missing (13): "**DueDate|RelatedItems|JIRA_id|Progress_notes|Next_action|Waiting_for|Updates**|*ID|Author|Editor|DocIcon|AppAuthor|AppEditor*"
- fields not in Columns (4): "**PercentComplete@odata.type**|*id|AuthorLookupId|EditorLookupId*"

**Risks**

- fields (22): "Title|Status|Category|DueDate|Probability|Impact|Exposure|Cost|Cost_x0020_Exposure|Description|Mitigation_x0020_plan|Trigger|ContentType|Modified|Created|_UIVersionString|Attachments|Edit|LinkTitle|ItemChildCount|FolderChildCount"
- missing (12): "**Owner|AssignedTo|Impact_x0020_description|Contingency_x0020_plan|Trigger_x0020_Description|RelatedItems**|*ID|Author|Editor|DocIcon|AppAuthor|AppEditor*"
- fields not in Columns (7): "**OwnerLookupId|Probability@odata.type|Impact@odata.type|Cost@odata.type**|*id|AuthorLookupId|EditorLookupId*"

**Issues**

- fields (16): "ContentType|Title|Modified|Created|_UIVersionString|Attachments|Edit|LinkTitleNoMenu|LinkTitle|ItemChildCount|FolderChildCount|Status|Category|Priority|DueDate|Discussion"
- missing (10): "*ID|Author|Editor|DocIcon|AppAuthor|AppEditor*|**Owner|AssignedTo|Resolution|RelatedItems**"
- fields not in Columns (5): "*id|AuthorLookupId|EditorLookupId*|**OwnerLookupId|AssignedToLookupId**"

**Decisions**

- fields (14): "Title|Description|Decided_by|Date_decided|ContentType|Modified|Created|_UIVersionString|Attachments|Edit|LinkTitleNoMenu|LinkTitle|ItemChildCount|FolderChildCount"
- missing (6): "*ID|Author|Editor|DocIcon|AppAuthor|AppEditor*"
- fields not in Columns (3): "*id|AuthorLookupId|EditorLookupId*"

**Changes**

- fields (13): "Title|Status|Priority|ContentType|Modified|Created|_UIVersionString|Attachments|Edit|LinkTitleNoMenu|LinkTitle|ItemChildCount|FolderChildCount"
- missing (14): "**Description|Action|Background|Impact|Impact_x0020_delivery_x0020_time|Impact_effort|Impact_functionality|Impact_cost**|*ID|Author|Editor|DocIcon|AppAuthor|AppEditor*"
- fields not in Columns (3): "*id|AuthorLookupId|EditorLookupId*"

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug in the current `/beta` endpoint around `$expand={field}($select={field})`. I'm seeing similar results.

I am however seeing the complete list of fields when I use:

`/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields`

I'm also able to return the complete set of columns, items and fields using:

`/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}$expand=columns,items($expand=fields)`

For the time being, you'll need to pull the entire collection and handle any additional processing in your app. Being a beta release there are several bugs still being worked out. This is why it isn't recommended that this be used for production.

Comment: understood it is Beta, there currently is no support for lists in the official version so I was hoping to use the Beta. Both workarounds you mention give me the same result as before (the 23 regular fields). Do I need to do anything special to get the value for a custom column, e.g. in my case: `Next_action`? How would I "pull the entire collection" and "handle additional processing"?

Comment: Could you add the column decision for `next_action`? I wasn't have trouble getting at the fields in my lists.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, what do you mean with “add the column decision”?

Comment: Sorry, my fat fingers trying to type on a phone with auto-correct. :) I was looking for the column _definition_ for `next_action`. I'm wondering if there is something unique about the columns that are not showing up.

Comment: definition: I have updated the post to include details about the lists I have. Next_action is a single line text string.